# Calculating probability of random draws

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We have $15$ balls in a bin; $4$ of which are blue and the rest are red. We draw the balls one by one and without replacement. What's the probability of drawing the $4$th blue ball on the $7$th draw?

What's confusing me in this problem is whether I should consider balls of a color to be the same, or treating them as if they are numbered? In the first case, isn't the probability just $\frac{ \binom{6}{3}15\cdot 14\cdot 13 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{15\cdot 14\cdot 13\cdot 12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider balls of the same colour to be indistinguishable. The probability is simply the product of the probability that only three blue balls are drawn by the $6$th draw and the probability that a blue ball will be drawn on the next draw. Thus, the probability is equal to the probability mass function for the corresponding hypergeometric distribution with parameters $N=15,K=4,n=6,k=3,$ which is $\dfrac{{4\choose 3}{11\choose 3}}{{15\choose 6}}.$ The probability that a blue ball will be drawn on the next draw is simply $\dfrac{1}{9}.$